# Pantalla simuladora de mensajes Android

Tags: android, android-studio

**Buenas, estoy tratando de crear una app que "simule" mensajes. Es decir, quiero que cada cinco segundos se muestre un mensaje y que se le de tiempo al usuario de responder. Hice esto para recrear la pantalla:

`resources/drawable`
**Para la respuesta del Usuario:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#9e9e9e"/>
    <corners android:topRightRadius="5dp" android:radius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

**Respuesta programada:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#642424" />
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="5dp" android:radius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

**Avatar:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#48b3ff"/>
</shape>
```

`resource/layout`
**Respuesta Usuario**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingVertical="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="60dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/respuestaUsuario"
        android:background="@drawable/respuesta_usuario"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Placeholder message"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Respuesta programada:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingVertical="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="60dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:background="@drawable/avatar_circulo"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nombre"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="Rose"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cuerpoProgramado"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nombre"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nombre"
        android:background="@drawable/respuesta_programada"
        android:paddingVertical="12dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:text="How are you doing? This is a long message that should probably wrap."
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**clase Mensaje:**

```
public class Mensajes {
    private String text;
    private boolean usuarioAcuatl;

    public Mensajes(String text, boolean usuarioAcuatl) {
        this.text = text;
        this.usuarioAcuatl = usuarioAcuatl;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public boolean esUsuarioActual() {
        return usuarioAcuatl;
    }
}
```

**Adaptador:**

```
public class AdaptadorMensajes extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Mensajes> mensajes = new ArrayList<Mensajes>();

    public AdaptadorMensajes(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void Agregar(Mensajes mensajes){
        this.mensajes.add(mensajes);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mensajes.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return mensajes.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        verTitMensaje poseedor = new verTitMensaje();
        LayoutInflater messageInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Mensajes mensaje = mensajes.get(i);

        if (mensaje.esUsuarioActual()) {
            convertView = messageInflater.inflate(R.layout.respuesta_elegida, null);
            poseedor.cuerpoMensaje = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.respuestaUsuario);
            convertView.setTag(poseedor);
            poseedor.cuerpoMensaje.setText(mensaje.getText());
        } else {
            convertView = messageInflater.inflate(R.layout.respuesta_programada, null);
            poseedor.avatar = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
            poseedor.nombre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
            poseedor.cuerpoMensaje = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cuerpoProgramado);
            convertView.setTag(poseedor);

            poseedor.nombre.setText(new PreferenciasUsuarios(context).obtenerPreferenciasNombre());
            poseedor.cuerpoMensaje.setText(mensaje.getText());
            GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) poseedor.avatar.getBackground();
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    class verTitMensaje{
        public View avatar;
        public TextView nombre;
        public TextView cuerpoMensaje;
    }
}

public class ParteUnoCapUno extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button eleciones;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    TextView historia, respuesta;
    AdaptadorMensajes adaptadorMensajes;
    ListView listaMensajes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_parte_uno_cap_uno);
    }

    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        int valorGuardado= new PreferenciaIdioma(ParteUnoCapUno.this).traerIdiomaGuardado();

        respuesta = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.respuestaUsuario);
        eleciones = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEleccion);
        adaptadorMensajes = new AdaptadorMensajes(this);
        listaMensajes = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mensajes);
        listaMensajes.setAdapter(adaptadorMensajes);

        if(valorGuardado == 1){
            eleciones.setText(R.string.btneleciones);
            eleciones.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    enviarRespuesta();
                }
            });
        }else {
            eleciones.setText(R.string.btnChooses);
        }
    }

    public void enviarRespuesta(){
        int valorGuardado= new PreferenciaIdioma(ParteUnoCapUno.this).traerIdiomaGuardado();
        if(valorGuardado == 1){
            AlertDialog.Builder menu = new AlertDialog.Builder(ParteUnoCapUno.this)
                    .setTitle("¡Elige una opción!")
                    .setPositiveButton("Hola", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            respuesta = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.respuestaUsuario);
                            respuesta.setText("Hola");
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Chau", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            respuesta = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.respuestaUsuario);
                            respuesta.setText("Chau");
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog listo = menu.create();
            listo.show();
        }
    }

    private final static int TIEMPO = 5000;

    public void mandarCadaCincoSegundos(){
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.postDelayed(this, TIEMPO);
            }
        }, TIEMPO);
    }
}
```

**Código de la actividad:**

```
public class ParteUnoCapUno extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button eleciones;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    TextView historia, respuesta;
    AdaptadorMensajes adaptadorMensajes;
    ListView listaMensajes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_parte_uno_cap_uno);
    }

    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        int valorGuardado= new PreferenciaIdioma(ParteUnoCapUno.this).traerIdiomaGuardado();

        respuesta = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.respuestaUsuario);
        eleciones = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEleccion);
        adaptadorMensajes = new AdaptadorMensajes(this);
        listaMensajes = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mensajes);
        listaMensajes.setAdapter(adaptadorMensajes);

        if(valorGuardado == 1){
            eleciones.setText(R.string.btneleciones);
            eleciones.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    enviarRespuesta();
                }
            });
        }else {
            eleciones.setText(R.string.btnChooses);
        }
    }

    public void enviarRespuesta(){
        int valorGuardado= new PreferenciaIdioma(ParteUnoCapUno.this).traerIdiomaGuardado();
        if(valorGuardado == 1){
            AlertDialog.Builder menu = new AlertDialog.Builder(ParteUnoCapUno.this)
                    .setTitle("¡Elige una opción!")
                    .setPositiveButton("Hola", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            respuesta = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.respuestaUsuario);
                            respuesta.setText("Hola");
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Chau", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            respuesta = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.respuestaUsuario);
                            respuesta.setText("Chau");
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog listo = menu.create();
            listo.show();
        }
    }

    private final static int TIEMPO = 5000;

    public void mandarCadaCincoSegundos(){
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.postDelayed(this, TIEMPO);
            }
        }, TIEMPO);
    }
}
```

En esta bellísima línea:

```
respuesta.setText("Chau");
```

Sale el el error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

¿Alguien sabe como puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se debe a que en el layout `activity_parte_uno_cap_uno.xml` no existe el `TextView` con id `respuestaUsuario`

Comment: Claramente, pero como es una vista personalizada pues como mencioné es un "chat" quiero saber como solucionarlo